# Missing required parameter for [Route: history_form.createHistory] [URI: history_forms/createH/{school_student}] [Missing parameter: school_student]

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-blade

I have a problem on my project. Here is the error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: history_form.createHistory] [URI: history_forms/createH/{school_student}] [Missing parameter: school_student].

I put the param above in my routes, my controller and my button too. Although, it returns a create method. How may I solve this? I have to take a student_id, but unfortunately it comes back as null

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/history_forms/createH/{school_student}', 'HistoryFormController@create')->name('history_form.createHistory');
```

Here is my create method:

```
public function create(Request $request, School_student $school_student){
        
        $page_title = "Dados específicos de Histórico Escolar";

        $school_Student = History_form::notesn($school_student->id);
    
        $history_forms = new History_form();
        $history_notes = new History_form_notes();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][0]['nome'] = 'Histórico Escolar';
        $data['breadcrumbs'][0]['link'] = 'index'; 

        $data['breadcrumbs'][1]['nome'] = 'Preencher Histórico Escolar';
        $data['breadcrumbs'][1]['link'] = 'createHistory';

        $data['route']              = 'history_form';
        $data['return']             = 'school_student';
        $data['lang']               = App::getLocale();
        $data['buttons']['cancel']  = true;
        $data['buttons']['save']    = true;

        $data['id'] = $school_student->id;

        $data['fields'][0]['id']            = 'school_student_id';
        $data['fields'][0]['description']   = 'Aluno(a)';
        $data['fields'][0]['placeholder']   = 'Aluno(a)';
        $data['fields'][0]['type']          = 'select';
        $data['fields'][0]['icon']          = 'fas fa-square';
        $data['fields'][0]['data']          =  $history_forms->id;

        $data['fields'][0]['select']['data']     = School_student::getStudent($school_student->id);
        $data['fields'][0]['select']['field'][0] = 'id';
        $data['fields'][0]['select']['field'][1] = 'name';

        $data['fields'][1]['id']            = 'stage';
        $data['fields'][1]['description']   = 'Etapa';
        $data['fields'][1]['placeholder']   = 'Selecione a etapa';
        $data['fields'][1]['type']          = 'select';
        $data['fields'][1]['icon']          = 'fas fa-square';
        $data['fields'][1]['data']          =  $history_forms->stage_id;

        $data['fields'][1]['select']['data']     = Classification_table::listGroup(2);
        $data['fields'][1]['select']['field'][0] = 'id';
        $data['fields'][1]['select']['field'][1] = 'name';

        $data['fields'][2]['id']            = 'teaching_unit';
        $data['fields'][2]['description']   = 'Unidade de ensino';
        $data['fields'][2]['placeholder']   = 'Unidade de ensino';
        $data['fields'][2]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][2]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][2]['data']          = $history_forms->teaching_unit;

        $data['fields'][3]['id']            = 'uf_school';
        $data['fields'][3]['description']   = 'UF da Unidade de ensino';
        $data['fields'][3]['placeholder']   = 'UF da Unidade de ensino';
        $data['fields'][3]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][3]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][3]['data']          = $history_forms->uf_school;

        $data['fields'][4]['id']            = 'year';
        $data['fields'][4]['description']   = 'Ano letivo anterior';
        $data['fields'][4]['placeholder']   = 'Ano letivo anterior';
        $data['fields'][4]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][4]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][4]['data']          = $history_forms->year;

        $data['fields'][5]['id']            = 'city';
        $data['fields'][5]['description']   = 'Cidade';
        $data['fields'][5]['placeholder']   = 'Cidade';
        $data['fields'][5]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][5]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][5]['data']          = $history_forms->city;

        $data['fields'][6]['id']            = 'uf_city';
        $data['fields'][6]['description']   = 'UF da cidade';
        $data['fields'][6]['placeholder']   = 'UF da cidade';
        $data['fields'][6]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][6]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][6]['data']          = $history_forms->uf_city;

        $data['fields'][7]['id']            = 'workload_offered';
        $data['fields'][7]['description']   = 'Carga horária ofertada';
        $data['fields'][7]['placeholder']   = 'Carga horária ofertada';
        $data['fields'][7]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][7]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][7]['data']          = $history_forms->workload_offered;

        $data['fields'][8]['id']            = 'frequency';
        $data['fields'][8]['description']   = 'Frequência';
        $data['fields'][8]['placeholder']   = 'Frequência';
        $data['fields'][8]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][8]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][8]['data']          = $history_forms->frequency;

        $data['fields'][9]['id']            = 'situation';
        $data['fields'][9]['description']   = 'Situação';
        $data['fields'][9]['placeholder']   = 'Situação';
        $data['fields'][9]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][9]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][9]['data']          = $history_forms->frequency;

        $data['fields'][10]['id']            = 'disciplines';
        $data['fields'][10]['description']   = 'Disciplina';
        $data['fields'][10]['placeholder']   = 'Disciplina';
        $data['fields'][10]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][10]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][10]['data']          = $history_notes->disciplines;

        $data['fields'][11]['id']            = 'notes';
        $data['fields'][11]['description']   = 'Nota';
        $data['fields'][11]['placeholder']   = 'Nota';
        $data['fields'][11]['type']          = 'text';
        $data['fields'][11]['icon']          = 'fas fa-book-reader';
        $data['fields'][11]['data']          = $history_notes->notes;

        $data['data'] = $school_student;

        return view('form.create_history', compact('data', 'page_title'));
    }
```

Here is my create button:

```
@if ($data['buttons']['create'])
    <button title="{{ __('Inserir') }}" type="button" class="btn bg-gradient-primary float-right" onclick="window.location.href = '{{ route($data['route'].'createHistory',['school_student'=>$school_student->id]) }}'">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp;{{ __('Criar') }}
    </button>
@endif
```

Comment: `$school_student` is called `$data['data']` in your view isn't it?

Comment: First, the code you're showing is not causing any errors because it's not being run – there is no `$data['buttons']['create']` in the controller code. Second, you aren't passing `$school_student` to the view.